# Comparing two records from different tables and deleting those that match

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is I am comparing two records from different tables and deleting those that match.

I have found this bit of code :

```
DELETE emails 
  FROM emails 
 INNER JOIN CustRecords ON CustRecords.Email = emails.email
```

Which works well, but I would also like to have a return value of how many records have been deleted.

Now if I do an SQL Query direct this is given to me but if I use my asp program it doesn't show a thing.

I know I have to use the count() function but I'm only still a beginner.

If possible I would like the count result as a variable like  `count = (how many records deleted)`?

Comment: Is this with a connection? Have you considered RecordsAffected argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i've managed to work this out... Seems to be that you can't use @@ROWCOUNT in an ASP line so i've got round the problem by using these 2 lines:

```
strSQL_count = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS 'count' FROM emails INNER JOIN CustRecords ON CustRecords.Email = emails.email"
Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL_count)

count = rs("count")

strSQL = "DELETE emails FROM emails INNER JOIN CustRecords ON CustRecords.Email = emails.email"
Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

I know that their is a simplier way of doing this but i'm only a beginner!!!

Thanks rlb.usa for you help

Answer (score 3):

How about appending another query after your first?

`DELETE emails  FROM emails  INNER JOIN CustRecords ON CustRecords.Email = emails.email ; SELECT @@rowcount AS 'RowsChanged'`

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: @OMGPonies My SQL is not too great - is there a way to do `SELECT @@rowcount AS 'RowsChanged' FROM (DELETE emails ... )`  ?? Racking my brain trying to think of a single-query one.

Comment: Not that I've seen - Even in Oracle, it's a separate query to get the info.

Answer (score 0):

**Better method**, assuming you're using an ASP database query:

You should note that the `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected as an integer. Like this (add try/catch'es, etc):

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("...");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE emails ... ", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();

        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Note this line
        // ...
```

Comment: Hmmm .. i'm a little confused with the last method how would i implement this into my stSQL = " .... ". Thank you for trying but i'm only a beginner willing to learn!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OUTPUT clause to send a list of identities that have been deleted to a table variable (or temp table) and then just select a count from that. That is, if you're using SQL Server 2005 or 2008. To best use this, i'd put it in a stored procedure so you can execute it and return the output, rather than having to mess around with multiple queries in your ASP code.

The code:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(ID INT)

DELETE Emails
OUTPUT deleted.ID INTO @TempTable
FROM Emails INNER JOIN CustRecords ON CustRecords.Emails = Emails.Emails

SELECT COUNT(*) AS DeletedRecords FROM @TempTable
```

I've tested this and it works, so it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm still learning abou stored procedures and once i've mastered how to do it i'm will certainly use your code.